# Magento2 redirecting to Shopping cart

Tags: magento2, redirect, addtocart, shopping-cart

Is there a way in Magento2 to have the user get redirected to shopping cart page after clicking "add to cart" - instead of the mini cart option at top of page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like `Magento1.x`, there is an option in `Magento2` admin panel to redirect to shopping cart page after adding product to cart.

Change the option as,

> Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product
>   Redirect to Shopping Cart->Yes

Comment: somehow I had missed that in the settings! thanks :)

Comment: A note that the configuration is now under Store rather than System.

Comment: Is there any way we can enable/disable per product level ?