# Magento 2: How to redirect to checkout page after product added to cart via Observer/Plugin from category page?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom, redirect, plugin

I have followed below & it works fine

[Magento 2 : Add to Cart Button redirect to contact page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121597/magento-2-add-to-cart-button-redirect-to-contact-page)

Only issue it should be redirected after product is added to cart.

I have tried different methods but seems not working http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

I tried using Observer but unable to redirect from Observer because of AJAX. It it's not AJAX then it works fine.

If somebody can guide how to redirect from Checkout page after product is added to cart. It would be better.

I'm using Porto Theme. So don't want to remove AJAX feature while Add to Cart

**[UPDATE]**

Through plugin I have achieved. Need to achieve something using Observer

```
public function afterExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject, $result) {
    $result = [];
    $result['backUrl'] = $this->url->getUrl('checkout');
    $subject->getResponse()->representJson($this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result));
    return;
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100417/42720 this?

Comment: Below is an answer to redirect to checkout by overriding template file, you can check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240628/44358

Answer (score 2):

try this code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url)
    {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we redirect to checkout instead of cart/index/ ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes you can redirect on checkout page as well, into above code instade of cart page URL just pass the checkout page URL.

Comment: yes i used this there, $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout'), still it is redirected to checkout/cart

Comment: Does it show any error or something?

Comment: No error, but its redirected to checkout/cart only