# Magento 2: Redirect from Observer Not Working on Category Page

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom, redirect, ajax

I have below code, which in not working from Category Listing Page.

Example: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/gear/bags.html

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/index/index');     
        $observer->getResponse()->setRedirect($cartUrl);
        exit;

        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        $response->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();
        exit;
        $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getResponse()->setRedirect($cartUrl);
        //$observer->getResponse()->setRedirect($cartUrl);
        exit;

        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
        $response->setRedirect($cartUrl);
        exit;
    }
}
```

It gives below error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setRedirect() on null in

In Plugin it works fine [Magento 2: How to redirect to checkout page after product added to cart via Observer/Plugin from category page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163322/magento-2-how-to-redirect-to-checkout-page-after-product-added-to-cart-via-obse)

How to use same thing in Observer?

Answer (score 1):

`di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect">
    <plugin name="NewAcctRedirectPlug" type="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Plugin\Redirect" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

`Redirect.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor_name>\<module_name>\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Redirect
{
     protected $coreRegistry;

     protected $url;

     protected $resultFactory;

     public function __construct(Registry $registry, UrlInterface $url, ResultFactory $resultFactory)
     {
         $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
         $this->url = $url;
         $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
     }

     public function aroundGetRedirect ($subject, \Closure $proceed)
     {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
         $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);            
         $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('checkout/index/index'));

         return $result;
     }
 }
```

Comment: hahaaha majak kari lo have nana manso ni @RakeshJesadiya

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from observer using below way,

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,   
    ) {
        $this->_response = $response;   
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
    $response = $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
    $url = 'custom url';
    $response->setRedirect($url);
    $response->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's not giving any error. But it's not redirecting :(

Comment: Try with updated answer.

Comment: Giving error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponse() on null`

Comment: Is it good to add exit by this way as per coding standard ?

Answer (score 0):

Redirection can be done by this, update this code inside `execute` method

```
<?php
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $redirect = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterfaceFactory')->create();
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout/index/index');
}
```

Comment: Giving same error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponse() on null`

Comment: I have updated the answer. If in case, you got that error even with the update one,could let me know which observer you are using?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponse() on null` Error

Comment: Could you please mention the event/observer you are using?

Comment: I'm using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. It seems not working on Category page

Comment: yes. you should try with the controller_action_predispatch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54986/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-saravanavelu).

Comment: `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` ? My goal to achieve once product is added to cart then it should redirect

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('contact/index/index');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();
    }
```

Comment: It's loading same URL in AJAX but not redirecting :(

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from predispatch event observer using below way,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,   
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;   
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $url = 'custom url';
    $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```